# No beta badges generated on cstheory.sx

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, stack-exchange

Check out https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/badges/16/beta

The badges are supposed to be generated shortly after private beta ends, I think.  cstheory is on day 25.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ack! a number of things didn't get done properly when cstheory went to public beta. Thanks for reminding me; fixing now.