# No beta badges were awarded for the Aviation site?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, private-beta, beta-badge

So we are 13 days into the public beta ([according to Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42572/aviation)) for [Aviation](http://aviation.stackexchange.com), and I just noticed that I didn't get the Beta badge even though I participated in the private beta.  Then I noticed that nobody else did either:

[image: Aviation beta]

---

### Update:

The badges were awarded the day before yesterday. (32 days into public beta)

Not sure who did it or what triggered it though....

Comment: Define "participated" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81727/beta-badge-how-actively-do-you-need-to-participate-in-a-private-beta-to-receive

Comment: @random: Upon further review, I got at least 10 bronze badges during the private beta.

Comment: There have also been a few times where the beta badge was [slow to be awarded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64152/no-beta-badges-generated-on-cstheory-sx).  Especially if nobody has it yet.

Comment: @Troyen: And the accepted answer says that it needed to be fixed.  Hence why I am bringing it up here.  :)

Comment: Looks like it's a manual process and someone just forgot to do that.

Comment: same situation over on [eBooks](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/help/badges)

Comment: It is a manually triggered badge because it's not one that usually runs often

Comment: @random Is someone going to manually trigger it then?  ;-)

Comment: There can be a delay http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/329/why-hasnt-anyone-been-awarded-the-beta-badge

Comment: @Sklivvz 25 days are considered normal then?